# Persistent path substitutions for C/C++ DevTools Support extension via Selenium

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, webassembly

I am launching Chrome via Selenium and loading the [C/C++ DevTools Support (DWARF)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cc%20%20-devtools-support-dwa/pdcpmagijalfljmkmjngeonclgbbannb) extension using the command line argument `--load-extension=/path/to/extension`. The extension is loading nicely, however, my path substitutions are not persistent. How can I make these paths persistent so that the extension finds my C/C++ source files?